# $\mathbb{R}^n$-flow, cross-section and Whitney theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, flows

For a $\mathbb{R}$-flow (X, $\Phi_{\mathbb{R}}$), the (local) cross-section is well defined (recall that a subset $S\subset X$ is a cross section of time $\xi>0$ if $S\cap \Phi_{[-\xi, \xi]}(x)=\{x\}$ for any $x\in S$). I would like to know whether there is some analogy for $\mathbb{R}^n$-flow (X, $\Phi_{\mathbb{R}^n}$). I don't know if someone already defined such cross-section for $\mathbb{R}^n$-flow or not. My thinking is that a subset $S\subset X$ is a cross section of time $\xi>0$ if $S\cap \Phi_{[-\xi, \xi]^n}(x)=\{x\}$ for any $x\in S$. Is this definition good? If the definition is as above, Whitney theorem (existence of a family of cross-sections for regular flow) holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$-flow? As well, is there a notion of expansive $\mathbb{R}^n$-flow which generalizes the $\mathbb{R}$-flow in the sense of Bowen-Walter?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find some answers in the theory of foliations.

Comment: Your question seems rather vague to me.  You are asking if a definition is good, but good for what purposes?  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @RyanBudney I would like to ask whether there is some analogy for $\mathbb{R}^n$-flows. I want to know how the theory passes to high rank flows in general.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. I am not familiar with foliations. I would be appreciated if you could name some references.

Comment: The theory of foliations is a gigantic field, and while there are some analogies with the theory of flows, understanding the analogies even in broad terms is going to be very difficult without *any* knowledge of the field. So I would suggest starting slowly, maybe with the Frobenius integrability theorem which you can read in many differential geometry/differential topology textbooks. I would suggest Spivak's "Differential Geometry", Volume 1, Chapter 6.